# Transforming raster to vector in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, features, raster-conversion

I want to convert from raster data to vector dataset using ArcGIS. Raster data consists of pixels and center of z values. Vector data sets consist of points, lines and polygons and x,y values. When I convert between data sets, how is the programme converting and describing from z value to x,y values? Shortly, how can the programme describe from raster to feature class?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are asking but I would expect that the raster cell values will become polygon attribute values.

Comment: DEM raster data includes pixel's Z values. when I convert this to vector data set, vector data set becomes points and point's Z values. is it true ?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from the inclusion of some pictures/screenshots to illustrate what you are trying to describe in words.

Comment: Actually, it is about flood flow using digital elevation model. I want to understand models, algorithm in ArcGIS Hydrology and Archydro. There is a algorithm called "stream to features". Stream is a raster data.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the RasterToPoint_conversion tool in the ArcGIS Help:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000007000000

This page is for 10.0, other versions might be slightly different.